# var exec = require('child_process').exec; callbacks for commands that run continuously

Tags: android, node.js, adb

I am trying to write an interface for the adb logcat command with node.js, and need some help having my function do continuous and asynchronous callbacks. This command generates constant output that I want to send to the callback function as it is generated (not after I let it run for awhile and then stop it). Is this possible with node.js, and if so how do I do it?

Here is my code so far

```
exports.logcat = function(options, callback){
    var logcatCmd = "adb logcat" + options;
    console.log("sending command: " + logcatCmd);
    exec(logcatCmd, function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if(error !== null){
            console.log("encountered error = " + error);
        }
        callback(stdout);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, no; you cannot `watch` shell commands for new outputs, in the same way you can stream data from a changing file or socket.

If it generates constant output, it's more likely it just reads from some log file and prints 
it on screen. You should figure out which file it's getting the data from, and use `fs.watch` with `readableStream` to continuously get the stream of data.

Comment: If I run a command to send that data to a file ie adb logcat > myfile.txt, can I use fs.watch to continually check that file for changes?

Comment: Well, that command won't run itself repeatedly, you probably have to put it inside a `setInterval`. But if you can do that, yes that will work.
But that would be no different from running `exec` in a loop, since `fs.watch` looks for change in last access/mod time, not change in contents.